# Need help getting this to work with PHP 7.1?

Tags: php

I'm long over do on upgrading servers and I can't seem to get this code to work on the new server, the default home.php does display but switching pages it does not (http://mydomian.com/?content=contact) Just stays on the home page.

Any ideas?

```
<?php

switch($content) {  
default:
include('home.php');
 break;  case "contact":   
include('contact.php'); 
} 
?>
```

http://mydomian.com/?content=contact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get query string by using `$_GET['content']`

```
$content = $_GET['content'];
if($content=='contact'){
    include('contact.php');
}else{
    include('home.php');
}
```

alternative:

```
$content = $_GET['content'];
switch($content) {  
    default:
    include('home.php');
    break;  
    case "contact":   
    include('contact.php'); 
}
```

Comment: 2nd one worked, just had to add ";" after $content = $_GET['content'] like you mentioned in your other comment. Thanks so much!

Comment: thank you. that was mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

There is no code getting the content of $content in php.
You need something like : `$content = $_GET['content'];`